# Offline routing library that can go along with osmdroid

Tags: java, android, routes, shortest-path, osmdroid

I have a tracking application and uses osmdroid library. My prolbem is that osmrdroid does not support routing. By the way the application is purely offline. Are there any suggestions that you can provide with regards to a library that supports routing, which can coordinate with the osmdroid map overlay. What I need to do is only calculate shortest path and draw it on the offline map from one point to the next.

I found this link:
http://code.google.com/p/j2memaprouteprovider/source/browse/trunk/J2MEMapRouteAndroidEx/src/org/ci/geo/route/android/MapRouteActivity.java

but I don't know how to integrate it on osmdroid application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in all osmdroid apps the map data come from a code line like this:

```
map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM);
```

This means the maps are downloaded as raster tiles, or if you have an offline application the maps are cached as tiles. So you do not have a graph of streets that could be used to calculate a route. So routing isn't supported in osmdroid for a reason.

To do offline route calculation you will need the street network data on your phone. Then you can use a simple wayfinding algorithm to calculate the shortest path. (like [Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm))

Comment: Ok I am myself working on osmdroid at the moment and I stumbled upon this app, which is opensource: [Osmand](http://osmand.net/) - I think it does what you need and you can also get the code here [Osmand Source](http://code.google.com/p/osmand/source/checkout)

Comment: I have seen the website but my main problem problem now sir is that I don't know where to find the right codes that could do offline routing... can you help me sir.